# How do we convert this Scheme (Lisp) function into C#

Tags: c#, scheme, lisp

In "Structure and Interpretation of Computer Languages" the authors show you how you can form pairs of integers in Lisp using `cons` (concatenate two values), extract the first using `car`, and so on, so beginning the start of a path to data structures.

They then go on to show you how you could encapsulate a pair of integers in a function instead, and proceed to rewrite `cons` and `car` in this manner...

```lisp
(define (cons x y)
  (lambda (m) (m x y)))

(define (car z)
  (z (lambda (p q) p)))
```

Took me a while to get my head around these two, but if I got it right, the new version of `cons` returns a function that encapsulates the two integers, and allows you to pass in another function that will do something with them. In the case of the rewritten `car` that second function merely returns the first integer.

Being a C# programmer by day, I wondered if it would be possible to do something similar in C#. Not that I can see much practical use for this, but more that it seemed like an interesting challenge.

However, I can't seem to find a way to define a `Cons(int x, int y)` method in C# that achieves the same as the SICP `cons` rewrite. Every time I think I've worked out what it needs to return, I then decide I got it wrong.

As far as I can understand, the `m` in the lambda in `cons` is a function that acts on the pair of integers, presumably returning another integer. This implies the return type of my C# `Cons` should be `Func<int, int, int>`. However, on second thoughts, it looked like it should return a function that takes a function of two integers and returns another integer, meaning it should be `Func<Func<int, int>, int>`.

However, I'm not convinced that either of these are correct, and even if they are, I haven't managed to write a method that compiles.

Anyone able to advise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The static types make this slightly more awkward, but you can pretty much straightforwardly translate the Scheme to CSharp. The return type of `cons` needs to be `Func<int, int, Func<Func<int, int, int>, int>>`: It is a function that takes two integers and returns a function that takes a function which takes two integers and returns one and returns an integer. To wrap your head around it, it helps to give the subtypes names:

- We call `(int, int) -> int` a *selector*: Given two integers, this selects one (first or last).
- We call `(selector) -> int` a *pair*: Given a selector, this returns the result of the selector applied to itself.
- Cons then has a signature of `(int, int) -> pair`.

```cs
Func<int, int, Func<Func<int, int, int>, int>> cons = (int x, int y) => (Func<int, int, int> f) => f(x, y);
Func<Func<Func<int, int, int>, int>, int> car = (Func<Func<int, int, int>, int> z) => z((int p, int q) => p);
Func<Func<Func<int, int, int>, int>, int> cdr = (Func<Func<int, int, int>, int> z) => z((int p, int q) => q);
```

To turn these into methods, you basically just have to convert a "variable" of `Func<T1, T2, ..., R> f = (T1 x, T2 y, ...) => ...` into `R f(T1 x, T2 y, ...) { return ...; }`. Exemplary for `cons`:

```cs
Func<Func<int, int, int>, int> cons(int x, int y) {
    return (Func<int, int, int> f) => f(x, y);
}
```

For the true main use case of `cons`, you will want to plaster `dynamic` everywhere, which enables you to build singly linked lists based on `cons` pairs:

```cs
Func<dynamic, dynamic, Func<Func<dynamic, dynamic, dynamic>, dynamic>> cons = (dynamic x, dynamic y) => (Func<dynamic, dynamic, dynamic> f) => f(x, y);
Func<Func<Func<dynamic, dynamic, dynamic>, dynamic>, dynamic> car = (Func<Func<dynamic, dynamic, dynamic>, dynamic> z) => z((dynamic p, dynamic q) => p);
Func<Func<Func<dynamic, dynamic, dynamic>, dynamic>, dynamic> cdr = (Func<Func<dynamic, dynamic, dynamic>, dynamic> z) => z((dynamic p, dynamic q) => q);
var list = cons(1, cons(2, cons(3, null)));
var first = car(list);
var second = car(cdr(list));
var third = car(cdr(cdr(list)));
Console.WriteLine(first + " " + second + " " + third); // 1 2 3
```

Comment: I love the way you said "straightforwardly"!! In all my efforts, I was way off what you achieved. I marked this as an answer, but strictly speaking, it didn't answer my question. I wanted to produce a `Cons` method, whereas you provided a variable that did the same thing. I tried modifying your code to turn it into a method, but got stuck. Any ideas? Thanks again

Comment: Also, as a slight aside: Is there any genuine use for an approach like this in Lisp? From my (very limited) knowledge of the language, it seems to be a complex way of doing what you could simply do with a list (that happens to contain two values). Is there a use case where this approach would give any real benefits? Thanks again.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel You're welcome. I've updated my answer to include how to turn these into methods. Why define `cons` in terms of a `lambda`? Mostly to prove the point that you can build a Lisp atop a very minimal and elegant model of computation called *Lambda Calculus*. Why define `cons` at all? Because a "pair" is effectively the smallest compound data abstraction you can get, in terms of which you can then define singly linked lists, binary trees, structs, whatever your heart desires.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel Of course you could also directly jump to higher-level data structures like most scripting languages these days do. Lua for example only has "tables", which are effectively "list" and "hash map" all in one. You can trivially construct pairs with lists or hash maps, but it's overkill; for example, if you stored a pair as a singly linked list, this would take two cons cells (one for each element). `cons` is simply the more fundamental abstraction here, and Scheme is pretty cleanly constructed "bottom-up".

Comment: Thanks for the edit and the explanation. Do I take it that there isn't really a practical use case for defining `cons` as a lambda? I mean, proving the superiority of Lisp is a noble aim (and something I'm hoping to be able to do at some point), but in your day-to-day Lisp programming, is it the sort of thing you'd do? Thanks again

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel I'm not a day-to-day Lisp programmer either, but I would take `cons` for granted; the lambda definition likely comes with significant overhead. I can't imagine it being done in practice except maybe when bootstrapping a new Lisp :)

Comment: OK, thanks for the reply.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel if your language only had closures and primitive data types and had no possibility to define compound data types, then what the book shows is that you could use the closures' memory as the data store. in case you were wondering what is closure, `(cons 1 2)` returns `(lambda (m) (m x y))` "where `x=1` and `y=2`". this "where" part is the "environment" attached to the lambda function so that the values of `x` and `y` can be known. without the environment, that lambda function would be invalid, containing "free", i.e. undefined, variables `x` and `y`. so 1/

Comment: ... the values are remembered / stored inside this environment, implicitly. so if we had no facilities to create compound data like record, struct, etc., but had these closures, we could use the closures as the data store. 2/

Comment: @WillNess Thanks for the comment. I did wonder about that, as the concept reminded me of the IIFE in JavaScript, which is how we used to get encapsulation in the language. Seems like it's the same idea.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel you're welcome. :) "IIFE" are "immediately invoked" (says Google), so they are more like a replacement for Scheme's `let`, I think.

Comment: @WillNess Yes, I guess you're right about the invoked bit with IIFEs. It was more the idea of encapsulating values inside a function that made me think. Either way, seems clear now. Thanks again.